# checking a word in the text and print() a command once

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using these commands I get the three sentences.

```
AnyText = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('AnyXpath')
    for AnyText1 in AnyText:
    print(AnyText1.text)
```

In the console, I get something like that:

**
1) Hello my name is John

**
2) Hello my name is Mark

**
3) Hello my name is Alex..

How can I check that all three sentences have the word "name"
and print("OK") if the word is in the sentence (element) and print("ERROR") if not.
Im try:

```
    AnyText = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('AnyXpath')
    Text = 'name'
    if all(Text in AnyText1 for two in AnyText1):
        print('OK')
    else:
        print('ERROR')
```

but this method only checks the first element (first sentence). I also tried something like this

```
AnyText = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('AnyXpath')
Text = 'name'
for AnyText1 in AnyText:
    if all(Text in AnyText1):
        print('OK')
    else:
        print('ERROR')
```

but I get many times OK or ERROR

**UPD:**
With a question on the text, I figured out with your help. Now I want to understand the numbers)

I have a loop that checks the next number more or less. If more, writes ERROR, if less, writes OK

```
sort_month=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[6]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[13]/table/thead/tr/th[3]/a[4]').click()

month2=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[starts-with(@id, "td_")]/td[3]/span[3]')
month2=month2.text.replace("'", "").replace(" ", "")
buffer = 0
if int(month2) > buffer:
    print()
buffer = int(month2)
month1=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[starts-with(@id, "td_")]/td[3]/span[3]')
for spisok_month in month1:
    spisok_month = spisok_month.text.replace("'", "").replace(" ", "")
    if int(spisok_month) > buffer:
        print('ERROR')
    elif int(spisok_month) < buffer:
        print('OK')
    else:
        print('==')
    buffer = int(spisok_month)
```

here I would also like to see OK or ERROR only once.
Any ideas?

Comment: the problem seems to be in the short form loop; if you change to the below does it work if all(Text in AnyText1 for AnyText1 in AnyText)?

Comment: ok the update is kind of a separate question, plus i have to agree a bit with @Sers below on readability, will have a look

Comment: do you need to update the buffer at every iteration?

Comment: @nickthefreak yes I get about a hundred different digits and compare more or less the next digit

Comment: see the update in my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the short form for loop in your first snippet. Basically it should look like the below:

```
AnyText = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('AnyXpath')
Text = 'name'
if all(Text in AnyText1.text for AnyText1 in AnyText):
    print('OK')
else:
    print('ERROR')
```

**UPDATE:**

On the updated part of your question, this is a different implementation as you have to update the condition in each iteration. For readability, it probably makes sense to keep this expanded:

```
outcome = 'OK'
for spisok_month in month1:
    spisok_month = spisok_month.text.replace("'", "").replace(" ", "")
    if int(spisok_month) > buffer:
        outcome = 'ERROR'
    elif outcome == 'OK' and int(spisok_month) == buffer:
        outcome = '=='
    buffer = int(spisok_month)
print(outcome)
```

Note: The update is almost a separate question. this means that either your first question was not representative of the actual problem or you should ask in a separate post

Comment: I think it is necessary to take out my second question separately from this.

Answer (score -1):

In you code `AnyText1` is a WebElement, not a text. You should use `AnyText1.text` to get text and then it will work:

```
AnyText = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('AnyXpath')
Text = 'name'

# AnyText1 is a WebElement and you should get text
if all(Text in AnyText1.text for AnyText1 in AnyText):
    print('OK')
else:
    print('ERROR')
```

Please check [coding conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) to improve code style.

Comment: please take a look at my changes in the question)

Comment: @keepomen there's no any challenge, you should try yourself implement the code. And definitely you have to improve selectors *по братски/